# Coupon code only applicable for certain product?

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes

Is it somehow possible to make a coupon code in the cart only applicable if a certain product is in the cart and only this product, no other products at all except one defined product?

Possible with standard Magento 2 features? If not, any extension out there that might help here?

Thanks!

Comment: Does my solution worked ?

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks! Is it also possible to get free shipping with the same conditions?

Comment: Yes there is a option, where you added the condtion , Free shipping -> set that to YES.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is possible with magento. You can make a coupon code specific for products, In admin panel

> Store -> Attributes -> product

Search SKU in default label and edit the attribute.

In **Storefront Properties** set **Yes** to Use for **Promo Rule Conditions**.

---

Now Go to **Marketing -> Cart price** rules and edit/add a rule.

In **Actions** Tab under the

> Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions
>   (leave blank for all items) -> Click `+ icon` and select **SKU**

and add only the SKU for which your cart price rule will be applicable.

If the coupon code need to apply for more than one product, instead of `is` select `is one of`.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Only one more: Is it also possible to limit this to only a certain SKU? So when the SKU and another is in the cart, the coupon should not work.

Comment: I don't think so it is possible using default magento option.. You need to customize the coupon code for that..

Comment: Using Magento 2.3.7 tried following instructions it does not work.